# Is $\mathrm{PSL} ( 2, \mathbb{Q} )$ a simple group?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

I am a new poster but I don't think this question has been asked before. Pardon me if it is.

Comment: $PSL(2,\mathbb{Q})$ or $PSL(2,q)$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I do mean $\mathbb{Q}$, the field of rational numbers.

Comment: Yes. ${\rm PSL}(n,K)$ is simple for any $n \ge 2$ and any field $K$, except when $n=2$ and $|K|=2$ or $3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. Is the proof easy? If not, can you provide a reference or a sketch of it (may be just for $\mathbb{Q}$ only)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment, ${\rm PSL}(n.K)$ is simple for all $n \ge 2$ and all fields $K$, except for $n=2$, $|K| \le 3$.

The proof is not exactly easy, but it is not impossibly difficult either. The field $K$ plays virtually no role, except in one place where we need at least $4$ distinct elements in $K$ when $n=2$.

It is in various books, such as Huppert's "Endliche Gruppen I", which is unfortunately in German. I have extracted the proof from some lecture notes of mine, which I took from Huppert's book. The proof assumes some results in group theory, such as a normal subgroup of a primitive permutation group being transitive.

Anyway, I hope this helps. You can find it [here](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mareg/lnqsimp.pdf).

Comment: Do you know what happens for $G = {\rm PSL}(n, R)$ where $R$ is a commutative ring? I've [seen](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf) that for $R=\Bbb Z$ the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ has index $12$ in $G$, so $G$ is not simple. What about other rings? For instance, are there some ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ (where $K$ is a number field) such that ${\rm PSL}(n, \mathcal O_K)$ is simple?

Comment: @Watson You should ask this as a new question.